# PHPmyAdmin mySQL Trigger: Upddate the parent table when child table was inserted, updated or deleted

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need some help with getting the syntax right to define a trigger in PHPmyAdmin.
What I have:
2 tables - invoice and invoiceitem
tbl_invoice has a field 'Total' which should show the sum of the 'Extended' price of the table invoiceitem

tbl_invoiceitem has 2 triggers that update the 'Extended' before_insert and before_update

What I try to accomplish:

Calculate the sum of all items for an invoice and update the 'Total' price in tbl_invoice after either new items are inserted or if the price or quantity for an existing item was updated.

I try to do this in PHPmyAdmin.

[image]

The error message is

[image]

I hope somebody can give mt a hint into the right direction. Just started with triggers and don't seem to find solution with a couple of days searching the internet.

Thank you for help in advance.

Cheers, Oliver

Comment: do not change delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 syntax errors in your code:

1. The delimiter commands should be outside of the trigger definition, not inside of it. Phpmyadmin should take care of this.
2. The commands within the begin ... end block should be terminated by semicolon (;), not by whatever you provide in the delimiter command.

I did not check if your sql commands within the trigger make sense, but the where condition of the set command does not seem right.

Comment: Yes your right. 1. Delimiter should be outside but looks like the PHPmyAdmin trigger generator has some limitations and is more for single statement triggers. I got it working by writing this corrected in a xxx.sql file and using the import in PHPmyAdmin. I'll publish the correct content a little later. might help somebody who got also stuck with the trigger page in PHPmyAdmin.

Comment: If myanswer helped you to resolve your problem, then pls mark it as accepted, so future viewers of this topic will know that the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found a work around:
write the full create trigger statement in a file and import with PHPmyAdmin.
 As 'Shadow' pointed out there was also a problem in the where conditions.
Below the corrected triggers that worked in my scenario.
There is a lot of examples on the net to get triggers done with the mysql client. This way you can use the exact syntax that you would type into a client and than import into PHPmyAdmin in case you can't reach the server your using with a command shell client.
Hope this helps other newbies.
Cheers, Oliver

```
-- after_insert trigger for InvoiceItem to Calculate the Total in Invoice
------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER `InvoiceItem_After_Insert` AFTER INSERT ON `invoiceItem`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @InvoiceNumber = NEW.InvoiceFK;
    SET @ItemTotal = (SELECT SUM(Extended) FROM InvoiceItem WHERE InvoiceFk = @InvoiceNumber);
    UPDATE Invoice SET Total = @ItemTotal WHERE id = @InvoiceNumber;
END
//
DELIMITER ;

-- after_update trigger for InvoiceItem to Calculate the Total in Invoice
------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER `InvoiceItem_After_Update` AFTER UPDATE ON `invoiceitem`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @InvoiceNumber = NEW.InvoiceFK;
    SET @ItemTotal = (SELECT SUM(Extended) FROM InvoiceItem WHERE InvoiceFk = @InvoiceNumber);
    UPDATE Invoice SET Total = @ItemTotal WHERE id = @InvoiceNumber;
END
//
DELIMITER ;

-- after_delete trigger for InvoiceItem to Calculate the Total in Invoice
----------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER `InvoiceItem_After_Delete` AFTER DELETE ON `invoiceItem`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @InvoiceNumber = OLD.InvoiceFK;
    SET @ItemTotal = (SELECT SUM(Extended) FROM InvoiceItem WHERE InvoiceFk = @InvoiceNumber);
    UPDATE Invoice SET Total = @ItemTotal WHERE id = @InvoiceNumber;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

The next 2 triggers are just single statement and are calculate the 'Extended' column in the InvoceItem table

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Calculate new 'Extended' price before insert 
CREATE TRIGGER `InvoiceItem_Before_Insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `invoiceitem`
SET NEW.Extended = ROUND(NEW.Quantity * NEW.Price,2)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Calculate new 'Extended' price before update
CREATE TRIGGER `InvoiceItem_Before_Update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `InvoiceItem`
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.Extended = ROUND(NEW.Quantity * NEW.Price,2);
```